# Swift 3 - MagicalRecord : How use findFirst on empty entitie

Tags: swift, magicalrecord, findfirst

I call the **MagicalRecord's** `findFirst()` method on an entity which is empty on the first run.

I have the error

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP...),

and if I insert one line before calling `findFirst()` method, no error (or if I call `findAll()` with empty entity, no error too)

So is there a method to call properly `findFirst` optional `?` Swift enforce the `!`

```
let user: User? = User.mr_findFirst()! as User?
```

Comment: User.mr_findFirst() as? User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed something when I was trying all possibilities... But after came back to basics, I found the solution :

```
if let user = User.mr_findFirst() {   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
let user: User = User.mr_findFirst()
if user == nil {

} else {

}
```

Comment: No sorry... Swift enforce wrapping mr_findFirst() with "!"